# Updating state and zipcode based on the IP address

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a field where user inputs Zip code. Based on the value entered I want to populate city and state. How i can do this in jQuery?

Comment: Your title and your question ask two different things.  Do you want city and state from zipcode or do you want state and zipcode from IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google's Map / Geocoding API, here is a quick demo:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zwPvs/1/

**edit**: Since the user is communicating directly with Google's servers, you don't even have to pass in an IP address, they figure it out. They may even use some additional points of data beyond IP address, but not sure.

Comment: i got this error:
Error: 'google.loader.ClientLocation.address' is null or not an object

Comment: @user695663 you need to check for null in the code.  This means that google couldn't find your location from IP address.